# NSJSONSerialization in iOS 5 like c# serialize to class

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, serialization, ios5

I am porting our C# MVC Repository code to iOS5 for the iPad. I have been working successfully with the calls to the services, pulling Json and serializing to built in NS objects. But this seems like a lot of work to pull the pieces out and then assign them to a class. In C# this is a breeze, just serialize to your class, mapped to the data attributes and you are off with a strong typed view model.

Anyone done something similar in iOS/XCode and I know you can use NSData in interesting ways, I am just not expert enough yet and I am looking for pointers and best practces.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, I'd say no.  Your best bet would be creating dictinoaries and then populate instances of your classes using KVO.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear to me. But as per my interpretation, you want to consume web service data in your application.In that case, see if it helps to you: 
Are you able to connect to web service and get serialised data from it? You will receive data in object of type NSData. Then you you can use NSXMLParser class (initialised with NSData received from web service) and it's delegate methods to parse the data.

This blog may help you:
http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/04/working-with-webservices.html

If you want to write serialised data, using NSJSONSerialization class then you can use

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

method. You can find details on developer.apple :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the [KeyValueObjectMapping](https://github.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping) project on github, it has some good support for object mapping(auto) and remapping if the property/class is named different from the context of the json.